# "That my results are not reproducible" or "that my results are unreproducible"?

Tags: writing-style, negation, writing, negative-prefixes, un-not

What is better to write?

1. > that my results are not reproducible
2. > that my results are unreproducible

How can it be re-written as positive affirmation (preserving the same meaning)?

Edit:
Do not I remember correctly that it is better to write negative sentence than positive but much more lengthy? This question is about technical copywriting.

Update:
When I was writing the question, I did not account for the fact that there are 4 "synonyms":

- non-reproducible,
- unreproducible,
- irreproducible,
- not reproducible

Update:
[the post with this phrase that provoked this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8445/when-google-search-gives-incorrect-results-how-can-it-be-reported)

Comment: "It won't happen again"? :)

Comment: What do you mean by positive affirmation? (Somehow, I'm reminded of Dave Barry: 'WRITING TIP FOR PROFESSIONALS: To make your writing more appealing to the reader, avoid “writing negatively.” Use positive expressions instead. WRONG: “Do not use this appliance in the bathtub.” RIGHT: “Go ahead and use this appliance in the bathtub.”')

Comment: This is strange that I did not read but remember it. That's why I asked how to re-write it in positive

Comment: As I suggested below, "singular" is the most accurate answer given that you want a "positive affirmation".  Singular has connotations so you must also elaborate.

Comment: wow, I am stuck to understand what is the best answer. They all were unexpectedly good

Comment: I read the page you linked.  I see no reason to stop using "unreproducible".

Comment: A reason that one would remain positive about this is acknowledgement for the bug reporter and the fact that you believe the bug exists. Since you weren't able to reproduce the bug, the exact conditions for the bug to manifest is unknown (to you). You could label the bug as `intermittent`.

Answer (score 6):

I would usually say not reproducible, and if I wanted to use a single word I would always use *irreproducible* rather than *unreproducible*.

Comment: Huhhh, I did not even think about irreproducible, updated my post after your answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

First part: “not reproducible” seems to be widely more used than “unreproducible”. I checked this on Google, the *Corpus of Contemporary American English*, the *British National Corpus*, and a Google search restricted to a scientific publisher website (*American Chemical Society*, acs.org).

Second part: it's hard to say something this negative with a very positive tone. One way to make it more positive is to hint at possible reasons why you could not reproduce the results, e.g., “my results could not, under the time available, be reproduced”.

Comment: Check "irreproducible". :)

Comment: @chaos, does not "irreproducible" have the connotation of well-established and commonly accepted inner quality? rather than something probed/questioned?

Comment: @vgv8: No.  I've never encountered the connotation you speak of with it.  It just means not reproducible (the *ir-* prefix being preferred to *un-* in the same way that we say *impossible* rather than *unpossible*).

Comment: @FX_, thanks, I did re-read it few times, yesterday and today. Thanks for your time! It was unexpected that "not reproducible" sounds better, I was inclined to think and use vice versa. I updated my question after studying your answer.

Comment: Question: does the asker want a positive tone, or just to eliminate the negative terms (un-, irr-, not-, etc).

Comment: In scientific results, positive tones might be unnecessary or dissembling.  It would be better to describe the concrete reasons to be positive rather than to use any tone.

Answer (score 2):

> that my results are non-reproducible

Both the prefixes *un-* and *non-* have the same meaning, but they are used with different perspectives.

In a note, the NOAD reports that

> The prefix *un-* tends to be stronger and less neutral than *non-*. Consider, for example, the differences between *unacademic* and *nonacademic*, as in *his language was refreshingly unacademic*, and *a nonacademic life suits him*.

Comment: This [NOAD](http://creativity-online.com/work/morgan-spurlock-noad-new-york/22299) ? No Advertisement?

Comment: It is the _New Oxford American Dictionary_, second edition.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what context the original poster is considering, but it should be mentioned that both examples given have a strong implication that the results are, in principle, incapable of being reproduced.

A "positive alternative" without this implication would be something like "the results have not yet been reproduced" or "my colleague was not able to reproduce the results"