# Using "not" versus the negation prefixes for negation

Tags: verbs, negation, prefixes, negative-prefixes, un-not

Let's take this sentence as an example

> He is able to move.

Now, what is the best negation of that action between those two?

> - He is not able to move.
> - He is unable to move.

And what makes one better or more correct than the other?

**Edit:** In case these sentences aren't good enough, give examples of your own if you please.

Comment: In that particular case, either is acceptable, and (in my view) neither is better than the other - at least in the absence of any other context.

Comment: In response to your Edit, I don't know what you mean. It's YOU asking the question - what are you asking for examples of?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["That my results are not reproducible" or "that my results are unreproducible"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11165/that-my-results-are-not-reproducible-or-that-my-results-are-unreproducible)

Comment: @TrevorD, you said - at least in the absence of any other context. –, so if you have in mind any example where one is better than the other please feel free to give it.

Comment: No, I don't have any in mind. Actually I meant in the context of what precedes or follows the sentence you wrote. Although I have nothing in mind, I can conceive that there might be instances where one might be preferred.

Comment: Why assume one of them is best? Which is best, butter or marmalade? Both are available because taste and habits differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Corpus of Contemporary American English, *unable to* is nearly eight times more frequent than *not able to.* The difference is even greater in the British National Corpus, where *unable to* is more than thirteen times more frequent.

You can draw your own conclusion from those numbers, although there may be contexts in which *not able to* is preferable. In practice neither is likely to be used as much as *can’t*, which is vastly more frequent in both corpora. For example, in a dialogue in which one speaker asks ‘Why doesn’t he get up?’ another speaker would almost certainly reply ‘He can’t move’, rather than either of the two alternatives.

Comment: The latin "alter" always refers to two, and only two possibilities ; I feel uncomfortable with "two" alternatives, four choices then. The meaning "a choice between many others" is widespread, such as in "the alternative medicines", but is it not still a mistake ?

Comment: I know what Latin _alter_ means, but that is not necessarily any guide to what the English word means. The OED’s entry for _alternative_ includes several definitions which mean two or more.

Comment: @MarkThorin: that is called the etymological fallacy. The meaning of a word (or phrase) lies in what it is used and understood to mean, and nowhere else.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is strictly the same ; when you have the negative form of an adjective ("-in", "-un", "-il", ...), and sure (*not* "inable" or "unaccurate" for instance !), it is always better to keep the affirmative form of the sentence.